# Registration using MultiView not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, multiview

I have a MultiView to add employees that has 3 views. Please let me know the right way. Here is the poor code that I made which is not working. It will give new errors every time I modify something.

Sorry I'm unable to post code here. Here is the post on ASP.NET forum

http://forums.asp.net/t/1825476.aspx/1?Registration+using+MultiView+not+working+

```
namespace EmployeeMultiView.AdminPages
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        }

        private void InsertInfo()
        {
            String KKSTechConnectionString = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KKSTech;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KKSTechConnectionString);
            //Session["sessFirstName"] = Request["textbox1"];

               try
                {
                conn.Open();
                String insertstring = @"Insert INTO Emp
                (EmpID,FirstName,LastName,MiddleName,Mob1,Mob2,Phone,Email1,Email2,EmpDesc,Accno,IFSCCode,Branch,ApproxUnitPrice)
                values (@EmpID,@FirstName,@LastName,@MiddleName,@Mob1,@Mob2,@Phone,@Email1,@Email2,@EmpDesc,@Accno,@IFSCCode,@Branch,@ApproxUnitPrice)";



                if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex == 0)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertstring", conn);
                    cmd.CommandText = insertstring;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox3.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", TextBox4.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob1", TextBox5.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob2", TextBox6.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", TextBox7.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email1", TextBox8.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email2", TextBox9.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpDesc", TextBox10.Text);
                  }

                else if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex == 1)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insertstring", conn);
                    cmd2.CommandText = insertstring;
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accno", TextBox11.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IFSCCode", TextBox12.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", TextBox13.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApproxUnitPrice", TextBox16.Text);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex == 2)
                {
                    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {
                        byte[] productImage = FileUpload1.FileBytes;



                        String insertstring2 = @"Insert INTO Cert (CertName, CertLogo)
                                                         values(@CertName, @CertLogo)";

                        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insertstring2", conn);
                        cmd3.CommandText = insertstring2;
                        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CertName", TextBox18.Text);
                        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@CertLogo", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = productImage;

                        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
           }

            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {

                string msg = "Insert Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }

            finally
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            InsertInfo();
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex += 1;

        }
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex -= 1;
        }

        protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Successful");
        }



     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to add codes, it says ident 4 spaces which I do not understand. So I posted the link where I posted question in forum asp.Thanks,

Comment: When you edit the post, simply select the code and click the button _{}_ on the toolbar

Comment: Okay thanks, I have posted my code.. Please check.. :)

Comment: You don't say what part isn't working or what error you're getting.  My suggestion:  work on each view's code until you can get that to work in isolation, and then try putting it all together.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue that you're going to have here is that, as written, you are not providing the correct number of parameters on the insert query for either the first or second views.

Some general pointers that may help you-

- Use switch/case rather than if/else if/else if pattern if you are always comparing the same value, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx
- Always use curly braces for if statements, even if it is a single line, it helps you visually scan your code and understand the structure.
- cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text isn't needed as this is the default value, although you can include it if you feel it improves readability
- Don't put quotation marks around insertstring in SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertstring", conn) - instead of the string variable insertstring you had already created, using quotes would leave your SQL command as literally "insertstring".
- If you have provided the SQL command as an argument (i.e. the insertstring above) you don't need to add cmd.CommandText = insertstring;
- Use meaningful IDs in your code, what does TextBox9 hold for example? What is the function of Button2? Having to go and look that up will make the code difficult to maintain and update.
- Make sure you are labeling your text boxes in the front end using the asp:Label control with the AssociatedControlID set to the TextBox ID.
- Make sure you are **validating** that your required user input is provided (use required field validators) and of the required type and length (set MaxLength on the TextBox controls to match the field length in the database)

I'm assuming your front end code is *something* like-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmployeeMultiView.AdminPages._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
            <asp:View runat="server">
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox1"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox2"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox3"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox4"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox5"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox6"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox7"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox8"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox9"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox10"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View runat="server">
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox11"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox12"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox13"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox16" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox16"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View runat="server">
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Text="Label Text for FileUpload1"></asp:Label>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextBox18" runat="server" Text="Label Text for TextBox18"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox18" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Next" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" runat="server" Text="Previous" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In which case I would write your code behind like this-

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace EmployeeMultiView.AdminPages
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0; //Even though you don't need braces here it helps readability
            }
        }

        private void InsertInfo()
        {
            String KKSTechConnectionString = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KKSTech;Integrated Security=True";
            //Store connection strings in your web.config file wherever possible

            //Session["sessFirstName"] = Request["textbox1"];

            try
            {
                //Move connection so we don't open it unless we have to
                string insertstring = @"Insert INTO Emp (EmpID,FirstName,LastName,MiddleName,Mob1,Mob2,Phone,Email1,Email2,EmpDesc,Accno,IFSCCode,Branch,ApproxUnitPrice)
                values (@EmpID,@FirstName,@LastName,@MiddleName,@Mob1,@Mob2,@Phone,@Email1,@Email2,@EmpDesc,@Accno,@IFSCCode,@Branch,@ApproxUnitPrice)";

                //Use switch/case to compare multiple values (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx)
                switch (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        //Need all the SQL parameters so we don't try to insert to the database here
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KKSTechConnectionString))
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertstring, conn);
                            //cmd2.CommandText = insertstring; - also redundent
                            //cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text; - this is the default value so not needed

                            //Add the parameters from the first view here, these will rely on ViewState which must be enabled
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox2.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox3.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", TextBox4.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob1", TextBox5.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob2", TextBox6.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", TextBox7.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email1", TextBox8.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email2", TextBox9.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpDesc", TextBox10.Text);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accno", TextBox11.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IFSCCode", TextBox12.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", TextBox13.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApproxUnitPrice", TextBox16.Text);

                            conn.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:

                        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                        {
                            byte[] productImage = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

                            String insertstring2 = @"Insert INTO Cert (CertName, CertLogo)
                                                     values(@CertName, @CertLogo)";

                            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KKSTechConnectionString))
                            {
                                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(insertstring2, conn); //No quotes
                                //cmd3.CommandText = insertstring2; - Redundant
                                //cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text; - this is the default value so not needed

                                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CertName", TextBox18.Text);
                                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@CertLogo", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = productImage;

                                conn.Open();
                                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Insert Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Session.Abandon(); - this would run multiple times during the process
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo();
            //Don't try to set active view index to non-existant view
            if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex < MultiView1.Views.Count)
            {
                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex += 1;
            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Assuming this is a "previous button" - may not need conditional if this is in the second view
            if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex > 0)
            {
                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex -= 1;
            }
        }

        protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Successful");
            Session.Abandon(); //Move to end of operation
        }
    }
}
```